# SQL intermediate table having column = max(column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: user and review, a one-to-many relationship.

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(*) totalReviews,
    USER . NAME
FROM
    review,
    USER
WHERE
    USER .id = review.user_id
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

I get:

```
1   2   marius 

2   2   daniela 

3   1   alin
```

What I want to do now is to display first 2 users because they have given the most reviews(2).

I tried adding having, if I hardcode `having totalReviews=2` it works, but if I write `having total = max(total)` I get 0 results, while if I'm trying with,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            count(*) total,
            USER . NAME
        FROM
            review,
            USER
        WHERE
            USER .id = review.user_id
        GROUP BY
            user_id
    ) A
WHERE
    total = (SELECT max(total) FROM A) `
```

I get an error (table A doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT u.id, count(*) as totalReviews, u.name
FROM review r JOIN
     user u
     ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY totalReviews DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

EDIT:

If occurs to me that you want all users with the maximum number of reviews, not exactly 2.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) as totalReviews, u.name
FROM review r JOIN
     user u
     ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
HAVING totalReviews = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                       FROM review r2
                       GROUP BY r2.user_id
                       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

Note that the subquery in the `HAVING` clause is simpler than the outer query.  There is no need to bring in the user name.